# Android single so for different abis

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have library project with precompiled so files. I want to minimize size so I want to use "armeabi" .so file for all arm abi's. (i need only arm code). To do this I put in jnilibs only the armeabi folder with the .so file.

The problem rises when i try to test this:
I created a demo app that uses my library project, the google play says i don't have a compatible device for this app.

1. Is it possible to use the same so file for all arm architectures and maintaining the size (in library project) ?
2. I don't care about preformance

Comment: what is your issue size or your device is not compatible with your device? And you cant use common armeabi file for all, because all have different implementation for armeabi.

Comment: the listing in the play store says it is not compatible with any of the "new devices" i have. Are you sure about the latter ? Aren't armv7a and arm64 backward compatible ?

Comment: Yes, an .so file built for `armeabi` should be compatible with `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` as well.

Comment: So why the play store entry says the app isn't compatible with any of my devices ?

Comment: I don't know. I guess you have something else in your APK that isn't compatible with your devices, but there isn't enough info in the question to say what that might be. You can easily test if the app is working on your devices by installing it with `adb install`.